# How to return the value from the proc using TCL

Tags: arrays, list, return, tcl, proc

I have a sample proc

```
      proc exam {return_value} {

        set input "This is my world" 
         regexp {(This) (is) (my) (world)} $input all a b c d 
         set x "$a $b $c $d" 
    return x }
```

After the above proc execution i will get all a b c d value in single list, so if i want only b value from the above proc, now am doing [lindex [exam] 1].
 I am looking for other way to get output in different manner instead of using lindex or returun_value(b) can give the my expected output

Comment: Clarify your question please. What exactly are you looking for? What do you think you should be doing to get what you want? Something like `[exam b]` to return only `$b` and `[exam d]` returning only `$d` maybe or `[exam a b]` to return a list being `$a $b`?

Comment: No @jerry that is not intention, i am expecting '[exam 1st_run]'. In this case after the proc execution If i want to get value stored in **b**. For example if i execute' puts $1st_run(b)' it should have "is"  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

The usual way of returning multiple values is as a list. This can be used with `lassign` at the call site so that the list is broken into multiple variables immediately.

```
proc exam {args} {
    set input "This is my world" 
    regexp {(This) (is) (my) (world)} $input all a b c d 
    set x "$a $b $c $d" 
    return $x
}

lassign [exam ...] p d q bach
```

You can also return a dictionary. In that case, `dict with` is a convenient way to unpack:

```
proc exam {args} {
    set input "This is my world" 
    regexp {(This) (is) (my) (world)} $input all a b c d 
    return [dict create a $a b $b c $c d $d]
}

set result [exam ...]
dict with result {}
# Now just use $a, $b, $c and $d
```

Finally, you can also use `upvar` inside `exam` to bring the caller's variables into scope, though there it's usually wisest to only do that with variables that the caller gives you the name of.

```
proc exam {return_var} {
    upvar 1 $return_var var
    set input "This is my world" 
    regexp {(This) (is) (my) (world)} $input all a b c d 
    set var "$a $b $c $d" 
    return
}

exam myResults
puts "the third element is now [lindex $myResults 2]"
```

Comment: Does the use of upvar here mean the same thing as pass-by-reference in other languages?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dict` and choose such key-value mapping that will make your intent clear:

```
return [dict create width 10 height 200 depth 8]
```

I think there are no ways in Tcl to return multiple values other than compound data structures or `yield` from a `coroutine`.